# Can't connect to MongoDB instance running on remote azure windows machine

Tags: windows, mongodb, azure

I'm having trouble connecting to a mongo instance running on a windows azure vm running Windows Server 2012 R2. I've verified the following things

- The network security group has rule allowing port 27017 inbound (* -> 27017)
- The VM has TCP port 27017 inbound open on all profiles (currently, my firewall is completely disabled)
- Mongo is running as a windows service. I've verified it is up and running. I was able to connect, insert, and find records in the shell on the remote vm that's running Mongo
- When I run netstat -a, I can see 0.0.0.0:27017 with the status "LISTENING"
- If I try to ping the VM, it times out (I believe this is expected)
- Port 22 is open in the firewall and in the network security group rules
- I am not running any 3rd party anti-virus software on my local machine
- I tried restarting the VM both from the OS and from azure portal
- I tried removing the rules from network security group and readding them

I've tried connection via SSH in bash on my local machine running windows 10 using the most basic command `mongo <ip-address>`. It times out with the message `ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable`

I've tried connection via Putty/SSH. Same result

I've tried connection via MongoDB Compass which gives a similar error `Could not connect to MongoDB on the provided host and port`

any ideas?

Here's the config I'm using

```
systemLog:
   logAppend: true
   verbosity: 0
   traceAllExceptions: true
   path: c:\MongoLogs\mongolog.log
   destination: file
net:
   port: 27017
   bindIp: [127.0.0.1, <external-ip>]      
   http:
      enabled: true
      JSONPEnabled: false
      RESTInterfaceEnabled: true
storage:
   dbPath: c:\MongoData\
```

Comment: And you've altered the mongodb conf file to allow for connections other than localhost?

Comment: It's a windows instance, so I assume you're talking about the config.yaml file I created. I didn't set anything explicitly, but the documentation says that it defaults to all interfaces.

Comment: I added the binding to the config file (updated post). no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the VM had multiple network security group profiles attached to it. When I click "Effective security rules" it showed a second tab that had another profile that appears to have been inherited from the subnet -- sufficed to say, it did not have the permissions that are needed. By opening the correct ports on that profile as well, connections we then going through just fine. We're gonna clean that up, but in short, there was a conflict of permissions.

Comment: I am also stuck with the same problem, how did you solve it can you please explain few details like what exactly you did under "Effective Security Rules"

Comment: @LuzanBaral In the blade that opens up with Effective Security Rules should (if it applies to you) tabs over the top of the rules. These represent different Network Security Groups that are affecting your VM. If you click each one to observe their respective settings, it should be pretty clear what needs to be done. For example, I had one that did not open the Mongo port and that was blocking it. I found that NSG and opened the port and all was good.

Comment: I did on the NSG for that actual VM (the one you create while you're creating the VM) but it applied another NSG to it which I think was inherited from the subnet. That is the one didn't have the rule set.

Comment: Thanks @Sinaesthetic for your time. I got it working somehow.